# Running multiple async tasks and waiting for them all to complete in django,

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a function which is

```
data=[]
async def connect(id):
    d= await database_sync_to_async(model.objects.filter())
    data.append(d)
```

and I call **connect** funciton like

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    # run_forever() returns after calling loop.stop()
    tasks =[connect(1),connect(2),connect(3),connect(4),connect(5)]
    a, b = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
finally:
    loop.close()
```

But this is not working,it says **There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'.**.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the doc for `asyncio.get_event_loop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop):

> If there is no current event loop set in the current OS thread, the OS thread is main, and set_event_loop() has not yet been called, asyncio will create a new event loop and set it as the current one.

A Django application typically runs multiple threads, in which case `asyncio.get_event_loop()` raises the exception you get when you are not in the main thread.

A possibility would be the following:

```py
import asyncio
try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
except RuntimeError:
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
try:
    tasks =[connect(1),connect(2),connect(3),connect(4),connect(5)]
    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Depending on which python version you are using (>=3.7) and what you are trying to achieve you could also use [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run).